# How can I backfill a decremental counter up a sparse pandas column?

Tags: python, pandas

How to create "Column B" from "Column A"?

```
    Column A  Column B
0        1.0       1.0
1        NaN       NaN
2        NaN       NaN
3        NaN       1.0
4        NaN       2.0
5        NaN       3.0
6        NaN       4.0
7        5.0       5.0
8        NaN       NaN
9        NaN       NaN
10       NaN       NaN
11       NaN       1.0
12       NaN       2.0
13       3.0       3.0
14       NaN       NaN
15       NaN       1.0
16       NaN       2.0
17       NaN       3.0
18       4.0       4.0
```

Comment: No worries, in the future if you paste your table /code / whatever in, highlight it all and then click on the button to mark it as code, looks a lot nicer for people to understand what you're after

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming empty cells are NaNs, you can use a custom [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.groupby.html) operation with a descending [`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.cumcount.html) and [`transform('last')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.transform.html):

```
# group by successive NaNs ending on a non-NaN
g = df.groupby(df.loc[::-1, 'Column A'].notna().cumsum())['Column A']

# compute the descending cumcount, subtract from original value
s = g.transform('last').sub(g.cumcount(ascending=False))

# keep only strictly positive values
df['Column B'] = s.where(s.gt(0))
```

Output:

```
    Column A  Column B
0        1.0       1.0
1        NaN       NaN
2        NaN       NaN
3        NaN       1.0
4        NaN       2.0
5        NaN       3.0
6        NaN       4.0
7        5.0       5.0
8        NaN       NaN
9        NaN       NaN
10       NaN       NaN
11       NaN       1.0
12       NaN       2.0
13       3.0       3.0
14       NaN       NaN
15       NaN       1.0
16       NaN       2.0
17       NaN       3.0
18       4.0       4.0
```

Intermediates:

```
    Column A  Column B  group  cumcount  last    s    s>0
0        1.0       1.0      4         0   1.0  1.0   True
1        NaN       NaN      3         6   5.0 -1.0  False
2        NaN       NaN      3         5   5.0  0.0  False
3        NaN       1.0      3         4   5.0  1.0   True
4        NaN       2.0      3         3   5.0  2.0   True
5        NaN       3.0      3         2   5.0  3.0   True
6        NaN       4.0      3         1   5.0  4.0   True
7        5.0       5.0      3         0   5.0  5.0   True
8        NaN       NaN      2         5   3.0 -2.0  False
9        NaN       NaN      2         4   3.0 -1.0  False
10       NaN       NaN      2         3   3.0  0.0  False
11       NaN       1.0      2         2   3.0  1.0   True
12       NaN       2.0      2         1   3.0  2.0   True
13       3.0       3.0      2         0   3.0  3.0   True
14       NaN       NaN      1         4   4.0  0.0  False
15       NaN       1.0      1         3   4.0  1.0   True
16       NaN       2.0      1         2   4.0  2.0   True
17       NaN       3.0      1         1   4.0  3.0   True
18       4.0       4.0      1         0   4.0  4.0   True
```